# Replicate Symbolab's Derivative Calculator

Tags: flutter, math, derivative

I'm building a derivative calculator flutter app and I've got the final derivatives covered using the `math_expressions` package (https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions). However, I'm stuck on displaying step-by-step solutions something like what the Symbolab's derivative calculator (https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator) does.
Any tips or suggestions on how to break down the differentiation process into steps? I'd appreciate any guidance or recommendations on algorithms, libraries, or methods that can help.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Note that asking for tips or suggestions on how to even get started on implementing a feature is effectively [off-topic](/help/on-topic). That's for you to come up with and just try (even if that means trying several different things). When you actually get to the point where you're written code, and it's not doing what you think it should be doing, and you're run out of ways to investigate the problem, that's the right time and problem to post to Stackoverflow. SO is here for "I tried doing X but instead of Y, it did Z". The "I want to do X, how do I do that?" phase is too early for SO.

Comment: I don't know anything about Flutter in particular, but from what I've seen, it is straightforward to encode rules for differentiating different kinds of expressions (polynomials, trig functions, exp/log, rational functions, etc), and the hard part is simplifying the results. I don't know whether you have a library available for simplification or whether you need to write that part too. A web search for "computer algebra implementation" or something like that might turn up some relevant resources. Good luck and have fun.